# Linux manual number in function bracket

Tags: linux, documentation

In Linux menu (man7.org), there are sometimes multiple pages dedicated to the same function. In these pages, there is a number in the bracket of the function. For example, for the `pipe()` function, there are at least two pages: `pipe(2)` and `pipe(7)`. What does the number stand for?

Comment: See [What do the numbers in a man page mean](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean/3607#3607)

Comment: Did you read `pipe(7)`? It's not about the function, it's an overview of the concept of pipes.

Comment: did you try `man man`?